# Can you suggest a route to travel from Moscow to Siberia and return in 2 weeks?

Tags: routes, russia, moscow, siberia

As an Iranian citizen I can travel to Russia via a 2 weeks tourist visa without permitting to extend my visa. As usual I will choose a return flight ticket from Tehran to Moscow.

Supposing it is possible to travel from Moscow to Siberia and return to come back home in 2 weeks, (consider spending at least 3 days in Moscow and 3 days in those areas) can you suggest most interesting routes to do it by train or taxi?

P.S: I do not know much about Siberia so please add a notable city or cities as my destination which I have to visit if I want to feel Siberia.

Comment: I think that moderators are being tough on closing questions. For me this is a real question. When it comes to traveling asking for suggestions are real questions!

Comment: This question is way too broad and therefore there is no real answer to it. Additionally, the most interesting route is also not very specific. What means interesting for you?

Comment: @RicardoAcras - yes they are travel questions, but this is a Q&A site, NOT a forum.  So the type of question needs to be specific and in line wit the rules in the [faq].  Questions not meeting these will likely get close votes.

Comment: @MarkMayo I agree the question is too wide. Just wondering, if, for expample, TS would have asked sthm like "Can you suggest what places in Siberia should I visit in order to see places related to Tzar Nikolai and his family?". Would it be ok?

Comment: @nikita, depends on the wording, and the community - but as per the [faq], if suggestions are being asked for, the poster needs to be VERY specific, otherwise it's considered polling and off topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have only 2 weeks - 3 days in Moscow = 11-10 days, then forget about European part of Russia and go straight to Siberia. I don't know why everybody suggests TSR, but personally it is very dull to sit in train for a week.

First try to feel Moscow life rhythm. You will see later how it is different in Siberia. 
Then I suggest you to fly from Moscow to Yekaterinburg and move from there by train. IMHO Siberia gem is in its **boundless** territory with some scent of wilderness. You can feel it only by traveling by train or car. In Siberia you can feel that Moscow is far away from that region (no wonder that fugitive serfs ran away to there to start a new life).

Try to visit Tomsk, Omsk. Visit Kemerovo to see industrial Siberia, though I think that it is the worst city in Russia 8) Then go to Altai. Altai is a must. Krasnoyarsk is a must too(Yenisei is a mighty Siberian river). From Krasnoyarsk fly back to Moscow. I don't think that you would be able to see Baikal due to lack of time. BTW Altai also needs extra time, but if you traveling around why don't visit it even for a while.

**Keep in mind** that spring is time when ticks wake up from winter sleep. Siberia was always in front lines of tick encephalitis infections in Russia.

Comment: @PersianCat Ticks yes. Nature is very close to you there 8)). Last time I was in Krasnoyarsk, "Stolby" nature reserve was closed to visitors because of bears. "Stolby" are situated VERY near Krasnoyarsk. Also you can see tick warnings in city parks near trees.

Comment: So do I need any medical considerations like anti insects or vaccines before the trip?

Comment: @PersianCat You can. But don't get paranoid about them. Just try to wear some hat and light pants so you can see ticks on them easier then on dark pants. Tuck your pants into the shoes.

Comment: So I can see them on my pants?! Amazing! :)) Thanks for useful advices! :)

Answer (score 9):

Maybe an obvious question, but have you looked at doing the Trans-Siberian Express instead of going back and forth to Moscow?

You could land in Moscow, catch the TSE to Vladivostok and fly back from there to Iran. Train travel time for that particular version is I believe 6 days.

As far as things to see in Siberia -- Lake Baikal is what immediately springs to mind, but by the time you get there you are almost in Mongolia.

Comment: Honestly I saw the tag and read the questions about but it was for travelers from Europe to Eastern Russia and China without suggesting any interesting route. And surely I wanted to know about road too if it can make the trip more interesting. Anyway thanks for your suggestion which attracts me a lot like an excited baby! About going to Mongolia I love it but as an Iranian citizen (I have only my Iranian passport) I can't travel there by ground from Russia or come back. For Mongolia I have to get there from Tehran via a return flight ticket. :)

Answer (score 9):

I suggest this route - Moscow, Nizhny Novgorod (very old and beautiful city, temples, architecture, museums), Kazan (one of the oldest cities in Russia. Recommend to visit the Kazan Kremlin, Kul-Sharif), Ufa (great culture and good people, rich Bashkir national cuisine. One of the best honey in the world produce here. And in this city I live.))) help you to solve any problems.), Yekaterinburg (the magnificent city, which was executed by the family of the last Russian Tsar Nicholas 2. a the oldest cities in the country), Krasnoyarsk, Irkutsk, Lake Baikal. This is the least that we can make it. However, I think, and this time you do not have enough.

Comment: Hi folks. I am soon doing a similiar trip besides that I ve got plenty of time. I was wondering about the cheapest and coolest way to get from Moscow to Vladivostok. I would do parts of the trip with the TransSib but I heard that the way from Moscow to Vladivstok is about 700$. Can this be true?  Also I heard about a sort of hitchhiker´s community that offers kind of guesthouses all around Russia. Ever heard of them?